# ruby heredoc and sprintf escape %: throwing malformed format sting %" (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, printf, heredoc

I am trying to escape `%` in a ruby heredoc.

```
property_str =<<~HEREDOC.strip
    function string get_type_name();
        return $sformatf("%%");
    endfunction: get_type_name

    property signal_x(ctrl_signal);
        @(posedge %{clock}) disable iff(%{reset} || $isunknown(%{reset}) || assertion_disable)
        (~$isunknown(ctrl_signal));
    endproperty: signal_x
HEREDOC
```

Then i am trying to print it

```
create_assertions.push(sprintf(property_str % {:clock => %Q(my_clk), :reset => %Q(my_rst)}))
```

As you can see I have double escaped `%%` the `%` but I still keep getting:

```
script.rb:518:in `sprintf': malformed format string - %" (ArgumentError)
```

Can someone point me where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that both [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25) and [`Kernel#sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) are interpreting the `%`s in the string. This:

```
create_assertions.push(sprintf(property_str % {:clock => %Q(my_clk), :reset => %Q(my_rst)}))
```

is the same as:

```
fmt = property_str % {:clock => %Q(my_clk), :reset => %Q(my_rst)}
create_assertions.push(sprintf(fmt))
```

And `fmt` will look like this:

```
function string get_type_name();
    return $sformatf("%");
endfunction: get_type_name

property signal_x(ctrl_signal);
    @(posedge my_clk) disable iff(my_rst || $isunknown(my_rst) || assertion_disable)
    (~$isunknown(ctrl_signal));
endproperty: signal_x
```

Note the `return $sformatf("%");` in the second line of the string. `String#%` will convert the original `%%` to a single `%`.

Then you put that string through `Kernel#sprintf` and it tries to interpret `%"` as an escape sequence and complains.

Either using only `property_str % {:clock => %Q(my_clk), :reset => %Q(my_rst)}` to build your string or, if you really must use both formatting methods, double the doubled `%`s in `property_str` so that `sprintf` will see `%%` and turn it into a single `%`:

```
property_str =<<~HEREDOC.strip
    function string get_type_name();
        return $sformatf("%%%%");
    ...
HEREDOC
```